# Как удалить все строковые литералы?

Tags: c, строки, компилятор

Я пишу программу для микроконтроллера, и в нём использую библиотеку для работы с матрицами Meschach. Библиотека не оптимизирована для работы с микроконтроллерами. В частности, там есть множество строковых литералов, предназначенных для отправки в стандартный выводной поток. Он мне не нужен, а литералы занимают слишком много места в исполняемом файле. Можно ли их убрать? В конфигурационном файле библиотеки я не нашёл макроопределений, позволяющих отключить стандартный вывод.

Под термином "убрать" я понимаю следующее:

- либо убрать все вызовы printf, чтобы литералы стали неиспользуемыми и оптимизатор их бы выбросил;
- либо превратить строки вроде `char *a = "aaaa";` в `char *a = "";`
- применить какие-то настройки компилятора, которые могли бы убрать все строки;

Компилятор: IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 7.50.

Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Ты чем-то не тем занимаешься. Чтоб крутить матрицы библиотека ненужна, тем более, если от нее исходят проблемы.

Comment: @Profesor08, вы предлагаете мне самому писать реализацию умножения матриц и векторов размером до 20х20, разложения QR и расчёта собственных векторов?

Comment: Ну а для каких целей там используется `printf`? Если для вывода отладочных сообщений, то можно обернуть их в блоки `#ifndef NDEBUG ... #endif` или прямо удалить.

Comment: @VTT, я так понимаю вопрос в том, как это сделать не перелопачивая весь код библиотеки

Comment: Попробуйте написать `#define printf`. Может оптимизатор выкинет строки

Comment: @VTT, как верно отметил @yrHeTaTeJlb, код библиотеки слишком большой, придётся перебирать около 75 файлов. `printf` действительно используется для вывода отладочных сообщений. Совет понял, попробую написать `#define printf`.

Comment: `#define printf` помогло, часть литералов исчезли из исполняемого файла. Но некоторые литералы кроме стандартного вывода используются также в построении какой-то таблицы сообщений, их оптимизатор не выбрасывает. Кроме того, есть литералы, которые передаются как параметры функции, в которой будет вызван `printf`. Такие литералы тоже остаются в исполняемом файле.

Comment: В принципе, я убрал вручную самый большой массив строк. Литералы ещё присутствуют, но они все короткие и их не так много. Так что изначальная проблема решена.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed -e '/printf/ d' ВашаПрограмма.c  > Результат.c

По комментарию TS:

1) "работает только на Linux" - кто Вам мешает поставить sed под виндой ?!
Это же СПО, а не *Photoshop* за 75 килорублей :-)

2) "удалять также и строковые литералы, а также одновременно работать с множеством файлов." - вот крохотный скрипт для bash:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                           
#                                                                                                    
# Скрипт просматривает вс файлы *.c в текущем каталоге и
# выполняет следующие действия:
# 1. Удаляет все строки, содержащие 'printf'
# 2. "Схлопывает все текстовые литералы: "abcd" -> ""
#
# Что именно делается, задано в файле команд команд sed,
# который называется process.txt
#
# Результат обработки записывается в файл с дополнительным суффиксом new.

for prog_file in *.c                                                                                      
do
    echo Обрабатывается файл $prog_file
    sed -f process.txt $prog_file > $prog_file.new
done
```

Файл команд *process.txt* для *sed* выглядит таким образом:

```
/printf/ d
s/".\+"/""/
```

Первая команда удаляет строки, содержащие 'printf', а вторая - "схлапывает"
текстовые литералы. Со второй командой есть некоторая проблема... Если текстовый литерал:

1. Занимает несколько строк
2. На одной строке расположено несколько литералов
3. Содержит символы \"

то всё это работать не будет. Ну я уже не стал так заморачиваться - в рамках регулярных выражений эти задачи решить невозможно.

Comment: Как я уже сообщал в комментариях, вопрос уже не актуален. Но ваше решение интересно, хоть и работает только на Linux.. Но всё-таки будет полезно, если доработать его так, чтобы удалять также и строковые литералы так, как я сообщал в вопросе, а также одновременно работать с множеством файлов. Тогда я отмечу ответ как принятый. А пока - один плюс))